# SQL - Counting number of sections of a course

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will pull a set of fields from a table called Courses. That part is easy. I would also like to have a column that counts the number of Sections for each course from table Sections. So you might have:

```
 Course Number| Course Name | Department | Number Sections
 12345           | English 101     | English         | 10
 12346           | Math 104        | Math              |  7
```

To do this, do I need to write a subquery? If so, how might that look?

Thanks in advance for help!
Paul

Comment: Please Add Your Tsql-Code

Comment: What code you have written ? What output do you get with that code? What is expected output?

Comment: add your query or elaborate question in detail with more data

Answer (score 1):

Its either a subquery or a group by query. Cant tell without the schema. Add the table definitions to your question and it will likely be a simple answer, unless this is already enough information.

As a completely guessed view of your data, it will be:

```
select CourseNumber,CourseName,Department,count(*) as NumberSections
from course
join section on section.courseid=course.courseid
group by CourseNumber,CourseName,Department
```

I'm really going out on a limb here though!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options:

```sql
-- left join
SELECT c.course_number, c.course_name, c.department, 
  COUNT(s.section_number) AS section_count
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN sections s ON c.course_number = s.course_number -- get section info
GROUP BY 1,2,3
;

-- sub-query
SELECT course_number, course_name, department, 
  ( SELECT COUNT(s.section_number)
    FROM sections s 
    WHERE c.course_number = s.course_number
  ) AS section_count
FROM courses c
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e9127/2)

The `left join` option is probably better since it's clearer to follow and may perform faster too.  Try running both and see how they perform, using an `EXPLAIN` if needed.

The previous answer uses an `inner join` which would result in no rows being returned for courses with 0 sections.

Comment: I used the sub-query option because I am including a lot of fields and didn't want to have to use GROUP BY for all of them. Works like a charm! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where a correlated subquery is a good option:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*) from sections s where s.course_number = c.course_number) as num_sections
from courses c;
```

Why do I propose this?  With an index on `sections(course_number)` this is probably the fastest method (unless your data is quite small).  This also returns courses with no sections.